# Facing issue while integrating identity server 4 with mvc 4.5 application

Tags: asp.net-4.5, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4 with Asp.net application MVC 4.5
when I run mvc application its comes to identity server 4 and shows login page. then after filling the credentials it validates the credentials and i have taken redirect uri as https://localhost:44367/Home/Secure. it shows the same uri in the browser but giving error

```
 IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
  IsReadOnly = False,
  Count = 1,
  Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
)
```

Why is this error coming?